# Select file lines based in one string array

Tags: c#, linq

I have one array with names

```
string[] arr = { "John", "karl", "Ralf", "Florian" };
```

And, I have one array of lines of one file

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("test.txt");
```

And, inside of that column, I have some names, random names, in a specific position of the line, for example, column 10 to column 20.
How I do this now, I have an encadead loop, where I search line by line from specific name of index of first loop

```
for(int i=0;i<arr.Lenght;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<lines.Lenght;j++)
        if(lines[j].substring(10,10).trim() == arr[i].Trim())
            list.Add(lines[j])
```

That is a very poor way, i know :(
But, I want to know, if is possible to do this using Linq, if yes, how it's possible ?

Comment: It's not clear how your file looks like and what data you trying to get

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should do the job

```
list = lines.Where(x=>arr.Contains(x.Substring(10,10).Trim()));
```

it will create a list from lines where line substring (10,20) is in `arr`

Comment: It should probably be `lines` not `lines[j]`.

Comment: @Alexandre look at intersect version

Comment: This isn't equivalent to OP's code. Both versions will return only substrings of the desired lines.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var result = lines
    .Where(line => arr.Contains(line.Substring(10, 10).Trim()))
    .ToList();
```

`Trim` on `arr` elements is not needed - they're already trimmed. `ToList` can be skipped to get a lazy `IEnumerable<string>` or replaced with `ToArray` if you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ, in query comprehension syntax:

```
var result = from line in lines
             let trimmed = line.Substring(10,10).Trim()
             where arr.Contains(trimmed)
             select line;
```

NOTE: `result` will contain an enumeration over **non-trimmed** lines, which is what the OP's code originally does.